# Image parameter in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Hy!

My site calling:

http://localhost:8080/WebTest/index.jsp?image=1.JPG

Code:

```
<img src=<% request.getParameter("image");%>  alt="1"/>
```

The problem is that no image is shown. The image is the right parth.

This is working:

```
<img src="1.JPG" width="3872" height="2592" alt="1"/>
```

Please help

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<% %>` won't print anything. Use `<%= %>` to print something.

```
<img src=<%= request.getParameter("image") %>  alt="1" />
```

It's safe to put quotes around the attribute value

```
<img src="<%= request.getParameter("image") %>" alt="1" />
```

But *much better* is to just use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) instead of the since a decade [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) *scriptlets*:

```
<img src="${param.image}" alt="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use

```
<img src="${param.image}" />
```